# Problem with Octal Conversion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to convert an entered octal number to its equivalent binary, decimal, and hex numbers.
But when entering large numbers, the result either falls short or is completely off the mark. Please go through the code and suggest a fix. 
I am a beginner to coding, so go easy on me. :P

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
  content="ie=edge">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
  body{
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
  }

  input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
  input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  }

  #Output1,#Output2,#Output3{
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
</style>

<title>Octal Converter</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center mb-3"> Octal Converter</h1>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="Input" type="number"
            class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3"
            placeholder="Enter the Octal Value....">
            <div>
            <input id="btn1" value="Go" type="button" name="Go" color="black"  class="btn button-danger offset-md-5 mb-1"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div id="output">

          <div class="card card-primary mb-2">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4>Decimal: </h4>
              <div id="Output1"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card card-success mb-2">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4>Binary: </h4>
              <div id="Output2"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card card-danger mb-2">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4>Hexadecimal: </h4>
              <div id="Output3"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>

document.getElementById('Input').addEventListener('input',
function(e){
  let num = e.target.value;
  document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click',function()
  {
  document.getElementById('Output1').innerHTML= parseInt(num,8).toString(10);
  document.getElementById('Output2').innerHTML = parseInt(num,8).toString(2);
  document.getElementById('Output3').innerHTML= parseInt(num,8).toString(16).toUpperCase();
  });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please share some "_large numbers_" which failed while testing.

Comment: Your input is allowing non-octal numbers. You must restrict to numbers between 0 and 7. This is octal number: 2543703. This is non-octal: 8392508.

Comment: @palaѕн Numbers like 123412654 and 12341265425612411 would work, but larger numbers like 12341265425612411512 and 123412654256124115122111 would give decimal values  and hex values which are way off and the binary equivalent gives a lot of 0's at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code can fail for several reasons. The test values you've posted in the comments (`12341265425612411512` and `123412654256124115122111`) are being truncated because they are **too large**. They will be truncated to the number of significant digits the system can represent internally, which is part of the language specification. In base 10, those numbers are `188,072,944,321,827,658` and `770,346,779,942,206,088,265`, which are several orders of magnitude greater than the largest integer Javascript can manage. More specifics on the size limitations for Number values in Javascript are explained below.

How to detect this kind of thing is a larger issue. You've said that you're new to programming, so here are some methodical tips that will help you to stay on a path where bugs like this are easier to find and fix.

In general, you want to write code so that these problems become apparent, and also so that small bits of code like this can be isolated for testing and for reuse. It's generally a good practice to write code that can be reused without being rewritten.

*Notes on your code*

**Input Validation & Separation Concerns**

Any time you take input, you want to consider how it should be validated and sanitized. You may have some bad input. If you're expecting an octal number to inputted, what happens if the program encounters a decimal number or something else? Among other things, it's possible to exceed the maximum number value that can be represented in the system, as you have found.

**The Maximum Safe Integer**

In Javascript, the size limitation for a Number parsed as an integer is named `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

If arbitrarily large numbers from a user exceed what Javascript can represent as an integer, the stored value will lose precision. Number objects are internally represented as double floats, so there is a size limitation in the implementation. Your octal input value is being read with parseInt, and the test values that you're using exceed the upper bound for Numbers that represent integers. This is part of the language specification, so it's not just a matter of writing a more-capable Javascript implementation.

From `http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5`

`The Number type has exactly 18437736874454810627 (that is, 264−253+3) values, representing the double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values as specified in the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic, except that the 9007199254740990 (that is, 253−2) distinct “Not-a-Number” values of the IEEE Standard are represented in ECMAScript as a single special NaN value.`

You can check your value against `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` to make sure your Number is in bounds.

```
if (your_number_value > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
    // ... the value is too large to be represented as an integer in Javascript
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

You can also test values using `Number.isSafeInteger()`, which may be preferable. I'm showing both, for completeness.

```
if (Number.isSafeInteger(your_number_value) === false) {
    // ... the value is too large to be represented as an integer in Javascript
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger

**BigInt - Arbitrarily Large Numbers**

If you want to be able to handle arbitrarily large number values, you'll need to use Javascript's BigInt type rather than Number. BigInt is the type designed to handle this problem of using numeric values that exceed what Number can manage. Most systems don't have a practical need for an arbitrarily large Number, but the BigInt type should be there for applications that need it.

BigInt is not fully available, yet. Javascript has many implementations and changes happen through a standardization process. The following link is to a recent version of the specification where BigInt has been specified. Its implementation is being worked on, but it's not available everywhere at present (Feb 2020).

https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-bigint-constructor

Due to those limitations, you've got a two-part solution.

First, you want to detect the problem so that you can potentially branch in your code, if for no other reason than to show an error.

Second, you can use that detection to solve your big number problem. You could theoretically parse and represent the number yourself.

**The Math.js library**

Doing an implementation of an arbitrarily large number type is a whole new problem, and it's not where you'll want to spend your time if you are a beginner. There is a handy Javascript library written for this purpose, which you could learn how to use. Here is a link to the BigNumbers section of the Math.js documentation.

https://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html#bignumbers

Here is a link to the page where the Math.js people describe a proof-of-concept for implementing BigInt.

https://mathjs.org/examples/advanced/use_bigint.js.html

That may be more than you need. Note that the changes below will show an error for these very large numbers, and it does take a very large number to exceed these limits. It's probably disappointing to think that there are limitations on Number, but the truth is that you won't really find a calculator in the natural world that doesn't have its limits. Better calculators have more generous boundaries, but numbers in the abstract are like the marshmallow man. They just keep growing and there's nothing we can do to stop them. In the real world, we can run out of bits. But again, even the limits for safe integers are relatively huge values.

**Javascript's Maximum Number Value**

Another limit to be aware, beyond the "safe integer" limit, is Javascript's `Number.MAX_VALUE`. This is the largest numeric value Javascript can store, regardless of what kind of number it is. Essentially the system can not manage values requiring more than 128 bytes, a relatively huge number for practical purposes. If you're writing code that can accept arbitrary numeric input, and perhaps if you are raising very large numbers to high exponents, values could theoretically exceed the maximum numeric value that can be represented in Javascript. It is unlikely that a user would have a value this large for any real purpose that is meaningful to all of the significant digits, let alone manually input a number this large into your calculator for any real, useful reason. But if numbers on that order are being used in a Javascript application, they will start losing precision beyond the value of `Number.MAX_VALUE`. You can test for this case and decide what to do.

Note that the upper bound of `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (2^53-1) is much smaller than `Number.MAX_VALUE` (2^1024), so if you're testing for `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` as an upper bound, you won't need to worry about the `Number.MAX_VALUE` limit. Just know it is there.

`Number.MAX_VALUE` on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE

```
if (your_number_value > Number.MAX_VALUE) {
    // ... the number is too large for the Javascript implementation.
}
```

**Event Listeners**

You'll want to reconsider the way you've set up your event listeners. The way you've got the code structured is not absolutely wrong; The "num" value will always be correct, but it's unnecessarily inefficient. You are running the outer event listener every time the "input" event fires, and the inner addEventListener function gets called every time. You only want to do that once.

You can read the full details of the input event here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

**Input Type**

You may want to consider using the default input type ("text") rather than type "number." I realize this may seem counter-intuitive, because the tool is for numbers, but you're really using that field as a text input field. Input fields of type "number" tend to bring up the number pad on platforms with soft keypads, but number fields have some attributes that you aren't using ("min," "max," and "step").

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

*Finding and fixing this issue*

First, consider factoring out some functions so that we can test atomic units of code, like the function responsible for doing the number conversion.

```
/**
 *  convert_octal_string
 *
 *  A function to convert strings representing Octals to other place values
 *
 *  Returns an Array of String values
 *  Position 0 - null if there are no errors, or an error string if something went wrong
 *  Position 1 - binary string value
 *  Position 2 - octal string value
 *  Position 3 - decimal string value
 *  Position 4 - hexadecimal string value
 */

function convert_octal_string (octal_string) {
    if (!octal_string || typeof octal_string !== "string") {
        return ["Error: function convert_octal_string expects a string parameter", octal_string, typeof octal_string];
    }
    var octal_string_len = octal_string.length;
    if (octal_string_len == 0) {
        return ["Error: function convert_octal_string received an empty string.", octal_string, typeof octal_string];
    }
    /* Only accept valid input characters (octal values) */
    var allowed_characters = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"];
    for (var i=0; i<octal_string_len; i+=1) {
        var each_char = octal_string[i];
        if (!allowed_characters.includes(each_char)) {
            return ["Error: convert_octal_string received an input string with non-octal values.", octal_string, typeof octal_string];
        }
    }
    /* Parse the number as an octal */
    var result = parseInt(octal_string, 8);
    /* Validation: Make sure we have a good result. */
    if (isNaN(result)) {
        return ["Unexpected Error. The given value could not be understood."];
    }
    /* Validation: Make sure we haven't exceeded the maximum possible value. */
    if (result > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
        return ["Error: Large Number. The given number is too large."];
    }
    /* Convert to strings */
    var str_octal = result.toString(8);
    var str_decimal = result.toString(10);
    var str_binary = result.toString(2);
    var str_hexadecimal = result.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    return [null, str_binary, str_octal, str_decimal, str_hexadecimal];
}
```

---

**Tests**

Write some tests that include good input/output and the input that is failing. The function above is written in a way that gives a consistent set of outputs so the caller can always understand what happened. The following tests are written as a simple structure that holds input values and the result we would expect from the function, if everything works correctly.

```
/**
 *  Tests for Octal number conversion
 */

/* 1. Some simple test data  */

var octal_tests = [
    {
        "name": "Basic Sanity Check 1",
        "octal_string": "0",
        "expected_results": [null, "0", "0", "0", "0"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Basic Sanity Check 2",
        "octal_string": "1",
        "expected_results": [null, "1", "1", "1", "1"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Basic Sanity Check 3",
        "octal_string": "10",
        "expected_results": [ null, "1000", "10", "8", "8"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Place value boundary 1",
        "octal_string": "11",
        "expected_results": [null, "1001", "11", "9", "9"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Place value boundary 2",
        "octal_string": "17",
        "expected_results": [null, "1111", "17", "15", "F"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Large number test using Number implementation",
        "octal_string": "123412654256124115122111",
        "expected_results": [
            "Error: Large Number. The given number is too large."
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Large number test using BigInt implementation",
        "octal_string": "123412654256124115122111",
        "expected_results": [
            null,
            "10100111000010101101011000101011100010101000010011010010100100",
            "123412654256124115122111",
            "770346779942206088265",
            "29C2B58AE2A134A449"
        ]
    }
];
```

---

**Run your tests**

```
/* 2. A simple way to run the tests.  */

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    /* 1. Check the tests */
    octal_tests.map(function (t) {
        var test_name = t.name;
        var test_input = t.octal_string;
        var results = convert_octal_string(test_input);
        var expectations = t.expected_results;
        if (results.length !== expectations.length) {
            console.error(test_name + ": Results do not match expectations for test", results, expectations);
            return;
        } else {
            for (var i=0, len = results.length; i<len; i += 1) {
                var each_result = results[i]
                    each_expected = expectations[i];
                if (each_result !== each_expected) {
                    console.warn(test_name + ": [FAIL] - result != expected value " + each_result + " === " + each_expected);
                } else {
                    console.log(test_name + ": [PASS] - checked " + each_result + " === " + each_expected);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}, false);
```

---

**Finally, hook up the UI.**

```
/**
 *  Octal number conversion UI
 */

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    /* 1. Get the elements you need  */
    var form = document.getElementById("form"),
        input = document.getElementById("octal-input-field"),
        button_calc = document.getElementById("calc-button"),
        output_decimal = document.getElementById("output-decimal"),
        output_binary = document.getElementById("output-binary"),
        output_hexadecimal = document.getElementById("output-hexadecimal");
    /* 2. Add a single click event handler. */
    button_calc.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        /* 2a. Get the inputted string, parse it into an octal Number value */
        var num_str = input.value;
        var result = convert_octal_string(num_str);
        /* 2b. Update the output fields with each result. */
        if (result[0] !== null) {
            output_decimal.innerHTML = "";
            output_binary.innerHTML = "";
            output_hexadecimal.innerHTML = "";
            alert(result[0]);
            return;
        } else {
            output_binary.innerHTML = result[1];
            output_decimal.innerHTML = result[3];
            output_hexadecimal.innerHTML = result[4];
        }
        return false;
    });
    /* 3. prevent the form from submitting, since it's not really being used. */
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }, false);
}, false);
```

---

**Full code**

Below is a complete version of the page, with all of the changes I have described above. I hope you find it useful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Octal Converter</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
body{
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.output_field {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <h1 class="display-4 text-center mb-3"> Octal Converter</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <form id="form">
          <input id="octal-input-field" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3" placeholder="Enter the Octal Value...." />
          <div>
            <input id="calc-button" value="Convert" type="button" name="Go" color="black"  class="btn button-danger offset-md-5 mb-1"/>
          </div>
          </form>
      <div id="output">
        <div class="card card-primary mb-2">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4>Decimal: </h4>
            <div class="output_field"  id="output-decimal"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-success mb-2">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4>Binary: </h4>
            <div class="output_field"  id="output-binary"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-danger mb-2">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4>Hexadecimal: </h4>
            <div class="output_field" id="output-hexadecimal"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>

/**
 *  convert_octal_string
 *
 *  A function to convert strings representing Octals to other place values
 *
 *  Returns an Array of String values
 *  Position 0 - null if there are no errors, or an error string if something went wrong
 *  Position 1 - binary string value
 *  Position 2 - octal string value
 *  Position 3 - decimal string value
 *  Position 4 - hexadecimal string value
 */

function convert_octal_string (octal_string) {
    if (!octal_string || typeof octal_string !== "string") {
        return ["Error: function convert_octal_string expects a string parameter", octal_string, typeof octal_string];
    }
    var octal_string_len = octal_string.length;
    if (octal_string_len == 0) {
        return ["Error: function convert_octal_string received an empty string.", octal_string, typeof octal_string];
    }
    /* Only accept valid input characters (octal values) */
    var allowed_characters = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"];
    for (var i=0; i<octal_string_len; i+=1) {
        var each_char = octal_string[i];
        if (!allowed_characters.includes(each_char)) {
            return ["Error: convert_octal_string received an input string with non-octal values.", octal_string, typeof octal_string];
        }
    }
    /* Parse the number as an octal */
    var result = parseInt(octal_string, 8);
    /* Validation: Make sure we have a good result. */
    if (isNaN(result)) {
        return ["Unexpected Error. The given value could not be understood."];
    }
    /* Validation: Make sure we haven't exceeded the maximum possible value. */
    if (result > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
        return ["Error: Large Number. The given number is too large."];
    }
    /* Convert to strings */
    var str_octal = result.toString(8);
    var str_decimal = result.toString(10);
    var str_binary = result.toString(2);
    var str_hexadecimal = result.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    return [null, str_binary, str_octal, str_decimal, str_hexadecimal];
}

/**
 *  Tests for Octal number conversion
 */

/* 1. Some simple test data  */

var octal_tests = [
    {
        "name": "Basic Sanity Check 1",
        "octal_string": "0",
        "expected_results": [null, "0", "0", "0", "0"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Basic Sanity Check 2",
        "octal_string": "1",
        "expected_results": [null, "1", "1", "1", "1"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Basic Sanity Check 3",
        "octal_string": "10",
        "expected_results": [ null, "1000", "10", "8", "8"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Place value boundary 1",
        "octal_string": "11",
        "expected_results": [null, "1001", "11", "9", "9"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Place value boundary 2",
        "octal_string": "17",
        "expected_results": [null, "1111", "17", "15", "F"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Large number test using Number implementation",
        "octal_string": "123412654256124115122111",
        "expected_results": [
            "Error: Large Number. The given number is too large."
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Large number test using BigInt implementation",
        "octal_string": "123412654256124115122111",
        "expected_results": [
            null,
            "10100111000010101101011000101011100010101000010011010010100100",
            "123412654256124115122111",
            "770346779942206088265",
            "29C2B58AE2A134A449"
        ]
    }
];

/* 2. A simple way to run the tests.  */

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    /* 1. Check the tests */
    octal_tests.map(function (t) {
        var test_name = t.name;
        var test_input = t.octal_string;
        var results = convert_octal_string(test_input);
        var expectations = t.expected_results;
        if (results.length !== expectations.length) {
            console.error(test_name + ": Results do not match expectations for test", results, expectations);
            return;
        } else {
            for (var i=0, len = results.length; i<len; i += 1) {
                var each_result = results[i]
                    each_expected = expectations[i];
                if (each_result !== each_expected) {
                    console.warn(test_name + ": [FAIL] - result != expected value " + each_result + " === " + each_expected);
                } else {
                    console.log(test_name + ": [PASS] - checked " + each_result + " === " + each_expected);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}, false);

/**
 *  Octal number conversion UI
 */

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    /* 1. Get the elements you need  */
    var form = document.getElementById("form"),
        input = document.getElementById("octal-input-field"),
        button_calc = document.getElementById("calc-button"),
        output_decimal = document.getElementById("output-decimal"),
        output_binary = document.getElementById("output-binary"),
        output_hexadecimal = document.getElementById("output-hexadecimal");
    /* 2. Add a single click event handler. */
    button_calc.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        /* 2a. Get the inputted string, parse it into an octal Number value */
        var num_str = input.value;
        var result = convert_octal_string(num_str);
        /* 2b. Update the output fields with each result. */
        if (result[0] !== null) {
            output_decimal.innerHTML = "";
            output_binary.innerHTML = "";
            output_hexadecimal.innerHTML = "";
            alert(result[0]);
            return;
        } else {
            output_binary.innerHTML = result[1];
            output_decimal.innerHTML = result[3];
            output_hexadecimal.innerHTML = result[4];
        }
        return false;
    });
    /* 3. prevent the form from submitting, since it's not really being used. */
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }, false);
}, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Numbers like 123412654 and 12341265425612411 would work, but larger numbers like 12341265425612411512 and 123412654256124115122111 would give decimal values and hex values which are way off and the binary equivalent gives a lot of 0's at the end

Comment: @AaronMathew Thanks for sharing specifics. Those numbers are too big. You get those zeros at the end because the implementation is rounding them off, keeping track of the high end of the value. A bit about the reason this happens and what you can do about it are described in my answer above.

Comment: `MAX_VALUE` is not his issue - you'd need 300+ digits to exceed that.   It's all about `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: @Alnitak I agree. I'm just trying to list the various issues with Number values. The original post didn't have specific values, but the author circled back and supplied them.

Comment: @AaronMathew Feel free to reach out if you have follow-up questions, etc.

Comment: @keparo Yea thanks for the elaborate explanation. I am still going through the code and understanding it. Thanks a lot.